# Populate drop down list from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have an ASPX page that has a drop down on it.

```
<div>
    <p>Pick a customer to show their order(s)</p>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="customerSelect" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="customerSelect_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

I want the options in the drop down to be populated from a database of customer names.

Here is what my database looks like

[image: database]

Here is my code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        populateDropDown();
        customerSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
    }
}

public void populateDropDown()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Orders]", new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"]));
    cmd.Connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader ddlValues;
    ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    customerSelect.DataSource = ddlValues;
    customerSelect.DataValueField = "OrderID";
    customerSelect.DataTextField = "CustomerName";

    cmd.Connection.Close();
    cmd.Connection.Dispose();

}
```

I've used this code before. So I must be missing something simple but I'm not sure what it is.

EDIT
I am getting no errors. The code compiles. But the drop down list remains blank.

Comment: In what way is this not working?  When you debug this, where/how does it fail?

Comment: I'm sorry. Should have provided that. It does not populate the drop down list. I get no errors.

Comment: "IsPostBack" and "SqlConnection" in the same code block hurts my eyes.

Comment: @granadaCoder why is that? Can you explain? I'm new to this so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: "Separation of Concerns" is the concept.  http://weblogs.asp.net/arturtrosin/separation-of-concern-vs-single-responsibility-principle-soc-vs-srp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Well*, I think you forget to bind your dropdownlist like;

```
customerSelect.DataBind();
```

And use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlCommand`, `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataReader` instead of calling `.Dispose()` method manually.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    ...
    ...
    using(SqlDataReader ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: YEP! Exactly right. Thank you! I will accept answer in 9 minutes.